# In AWS Codestar, how to configure branch deployments to specific environments?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation, aws-codestar

I just created a brand new AWS Codestar project.

As far as I can tell, that Codestar is just a dashboard that integrates multiple AWS products.

There is one thing that I don't know how to configure yet, and it is branch deployments.

In my git repository, I have 3 branches: `master`, `develop` and `staging`

In an ideal world, `master` deploys to production, `develop` to the development environment and `staging` to the QA environment.

I don't know how to configure this pipeline using AWS, and I haven't been able to locate to relevant documentation in their developers portal.

This is my `buildspec.yml` file just in case it can be configured there:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - echo Installing NPM Packages...
      - npm install
  build:
    commands:
      - aws cloudformation package --template template.yml --s3-bucket $S3_BUCKET --output-template template-export.yml

artifacts:
  type: zip
  files:
    - template-export.yml
```

This is a project that uses AWS API Gateway to route requests to AWS Lambda functions if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly AWS CodePipline doesn't support passing in the git branch. Last year they have only added support to pass the git commit sha1 (more can be found [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=740211#740211)).

I'd suggest you follow the CodePipline docs [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/pipelines-create.html), to create 3 pipelines one for each branch (you can even create a special buildspec_dev.yaml or buildspec_prod.yaml, check out more examples [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec-ref-name-storage)).